# Sage CRM web services example in Python

Tags: python, soap, crm, sage-crm

I am trying to write a Python consumer for Sage CRM using their Web Services interface. I am using SOAPpy as Python SOAP library (not married to it, was easy to install on Ubuntu so went with it).

Managed to fetch the WSDL using the Proxy and executed the logon method exposed by Sage CRM.

```
from SOAPpy import *
proxy = WSDL.Proxy('http://192.168.0.3/MATE/eware.dll/webservice/webservice.wsdl')
```

It returns a session object which sort of looks like

```
SOAPpy.Types.structType result at 151924492: {'sessionid': '170911104429792'}
```

Now I am trying to use Sage CRM's queryrecord method to query the data, and that returns

```
Fault SOAP-ENV:Server: No active usersession detected
```

Reading the documentation reveals that I have to send back to the session id that recd. when I logged in back with each requests.

According to the Sage documentation I have to send it back as such

```
SID = binding.logon("admin", ""); 
binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader(); 
binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = SID.sessionid;
```

Any ideas how to do append this to the headers using SOAPpy?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just to comment on SOAPpy vs. other soap libraries... SOAPpy traditionally has been the easy-to-use library that didn't support complex data structures.  So if it works for your case then you are better off.  For more complex data structures in the WSDL you'd need to move ZSI.

Anyway, the documentation link for the project on SourceForge seems to be broken, so I'll just cut+paste the header documentation here with some minor formatting changes:

### Using Headers

SOAPpy has a Header class to hold data for the header of a SOAP message.
Each Header instance has methods to set/get the  MustUnderstand attribute, and
methods to set/get the Actor attribute.

SOAPpy also has a SOAPContext class so that each server method can be 
implemented in such a way that it gets the context of the connecting client.
This includes both common SOAP information and connection information (see 
below for an example).

### Client Examples

```
import SOAPpy
test = 42
server = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy("http://localhost:8888")
server = server._sa ("urn:soapinterop")

hd = SOAPpy.Header()
hd.InteropTestHeader ='This should fault, as you don\'t understand the header.'
hd._setMustUnderstand ('InteropTestHeader', 0)
hd._setActor ('InteropTestHeader','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next')
server = server._hd (hd)

print server.echoInteger (test)
```

This should succeed (provided the server has defined echoInteger), as it
builds a valid header into this client with MustUnderstand set to 0
and then sends the SOAP with this header.

```
import SOAPpy
test = 42
server = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy("http://localhost:8888")
server = server._sa ("urn:soapinterop")
#Header
hd = SOAPpy.Header()
hd.InteropTestHeader = 'This should fault,as you don\'t understand the header.'
hd._setMustUnderstand ('InteropTestHeader', 1)
hd._setActor ('InteropTestHeader','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next')
server = server._hd (hd)

print server.echoInteger (test)
```

This should fail (even if the server has defined 'echoInteger'), as it
builds a valid header into this client, but sets MustUnderstand to 1
for a message that the server presumably won't understand before sending.

Comment: Appreciate your response Van.

Which version of SOAPpy does SOAPpy.Header ship with? My Ubuntu (Hardy) machine distributes 0.12.0-2 and doesn't seem to have SOAPpy.Header.

I did find some documentation regarding SOAPpy.Header during my Google around and was at a loss when the I couldn't find it in the package.

Do I have to fetch SOAPpy from SVN?

Comment: Hi Devraj, it looks like 0.12.0 is the latest packaged version, so that means you'll need to get it from SVN at http://pywebsvcs.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywebsvcs/trunk/SOAPpy/

Answer (score 0):

Am just figuring this out too.  I have the core of this done though, so this ought to speed things up for anyone else who needs this! I am assuming other Sage subsystems work the same way (but I don't yet know), so I tried to account for that possibility.

First, you need this module I wrote called pySage.py.  It defines a class for running a process which you'll need to subclass for your custom use.

```
#----------------------------
#
# pySage.py
#
# Author: BuvinJ
# Created: December, 2015
#
# This module defines the SageProcess class.
# This class handles connecting and disconnecting
# to Sage web services, and provides an object
# through which the web services can be accessed.
#
#----------------------------

# Download SOAPpy from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SOAPpy
from SOAPpy import WSDL, Types as soapTypes

from enum import Enum
SageSubsystem = Enum( 'SageSubsystem', 'CRM' )

# Define your sub system connection parameters here.
CRM_WSDL_FILE_URL = "http://CRMservername/CRMinstallname/eWare.dll/webservice/webservice.wsdl"    
CRM_USER          = "admin"
CRM_PASSWORD      = ""
CRM_NAMESPACE     = "http://tempuri.org/type"

#----------------------------
# SageProcess Class

# To use this class:
#
# 1) Create a SageProcess subclass and define the method 
#    body(). 
# 2) Instanitate an instance of the subclass, passing a
#    SageSubsystem enumeration, e.g. SageSubsystem.CRM.
# 3) Invoke the run() method of the process instance.
#    This will in turn invoke body() to execute your 
#    custom actions.
#
# To access the sage web services, use the "sage" member of 
# a SageProcess instance. For help using Sage web service
# objects see: 
# https://community.sagecrm.com/developerhelp/default.htm
#
# You may also invoke the sageHelp() method of a SageProcess 
# instance to view the top level web service object members. 
# Or, recordHelp( sageRecord ) to view the members of the 
# various record objects returned by the web services.
#
#----------------------------
class SageProcess():

    # Construction & service connection methods
    #----------------------------

    def __init__( self, subsystem, verbose=False ):
        """
        @param subsystem: The Sage subsystem on which to run the process. Ex. SageSubsystem.CRM
        @param verbose: If True, details of the SOAP exchange are displayed.
        """        
        self.subsystem = subsystem
        self.verbose = verbose        
        if self.subsystem == SageSubsystem.CRM :
            self.wsdl      = CRM_WSDL_FILE_URL
            self.namespace = CRM_NAMESPACE
            self.username  = CRM_USER
            self.password  = CRM_PASSWORD
        else :
            self.abort( "Unknown subsystem specified!" )   
        self.sessionId = None                    
        self.connect()

    def connect( self ) :               
        try :
            self.sage = WSDL.Proxy( self.wsdl, namespace=self.namespace )            
        except :
            self.abort( "WSDL failure. This is may be caused by access settings. File url: " + CRM_WSDL_FILE_URL )                
        if self.verbose : "Connected to web service."
        self.soapProxy = self.sage.soapproxy        
        if self.verbose : self.sageDebug()

    # Core process methods
    #----------------------------        

    def run( self ) :        
        if not self.logOn( self.username, self.password ) : 
            self.abort( "Log On failed!" )    
        else :
            if self.verbose : 
                print "Logged On. Session Id: " + str( self.sessionId )            
        self.appendSessionHeader()               
        self.body()
        if self.logOff() : 
            if self.verbose : print "Logged Off."

    def logOn( self, username, password ) : 
        try : self.sessionId = self.sage.logon( username, password ).sessionid
        except Exception as e: 
            self.abortOnException( "Log On failure.\n(You may need to enable forced logins.)", e )
        return (self.sessionId is not None)

    def appendSessionHeader( self ) : 
        self.soapProxy = self.soapProxy._sa( "urn:sessionid" )
        soapHeader = soapTypes.headerType()
        soapHeader.SessionHeader = soapTypes.structType( None, "SessionHeader" )
        soapHeader.SessionHeader.sessionId = soapTypes.stringType( self.sessionId )
        self.soapProxy = self.soapProxy._hd( soapHeader )
        self.sage.soapproxy = self.soapProxy

    def body( self ) : 
        """
        You should override this method when you subclass SageProcess. 
        It will be called after logging on, and will be followed by logging off.
        Use self.sage to access the system from within this method.
        """

    def logOff( self ) : 
        success = False
        try : success = self.sage.logoff( self.sessionId )
        except Exception as e: self.abortOnException( "Log off failure.", e )   
        return success

    # Helper methods
    #----------------------------   

    # Immediately exit the program with an indication of success
    def quit( self, msg=None ) :
        if msg is not None: print msg
        import os
        os._exit( 0 )      

    # Immediately exit the program with an error
    def abort( self, msg=None, errorCode=1 ) :        
        if msg is not None: print msg
        print "Process terminated..."
        import os
        os._exit( errorCode )      

    # Immediately exit the program with an Exception error
    def abortOnException( self, e, msg=None, errorCode=1 ) :
        if msg is not None: print msg
        print ""
        print e 
        print ""
        self.abort( None, errorCode )      

    def sageDebug( self, enable=True ) : 
        if enable : self.soapProxy.config.debug = 1
        else :      self.soapProxy.config.debug = 0       

    def sageHelp( self ) : 
        print "\nSage web service methods:\n"        
        self.sage.show_methods()

    def recordHelp( self, record, typeDescr=None ) :         
        if record is None : return
        print ""        
        description = "record object members:\n"
        if typeDescr is not None : 
            description = typeDescr + " " + description
        print description
        print dir( record )
        print ""
```

Then, add a client for this class.  Here's an example I created called fetch_company_data_example.py:

```
#----------------------------
#
#  fetch_company_data_example.py
#
#----------------------------

from pySage import SageProcess, SageSubsystem

def main() :

    # Get process parameters from the command line
    import sys
    try :
        companyId = sys.argv[1]
    except : 
        abort( "Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " companyId [-v] [--verbose]" )       
    verbose = False
    try :
        if ( sys.argv[2] == "-v" or 
             sys.argv[2] == "--verbose" ) :
            verbose = True
    except : pass

    # Create & run the custom Sage process
    process = FetchCompanyDataProcess( companyId, verbose )
    process.run()

class FetchCompanyDataProcess( SageProcess ):

    def __init__( self, companyId, verbose ):
        SageProcess.__init__( self, SageSubsystem.CRM, verbose )
        self.companyId = companyId

    def body( self ):   

        # Fetch the company record (exiting if no data is returned)
        companyRecord = self.getCompanyRecord()
        if companyRecord is None: self.quit( "\nNo records found.\n" )                

        # Uncomment for development help...
        #if self.verbose : self.recordHelp( companyRecord, "Company" )        
        #if self.verbose : self.recordHelp( companyRecord.address.records, "Address" )        

        # Print some of the company info 
        print "" 
        print "Company Id: " + self.companyId
        print "Name: " + companyRecord.name
        print "Location: " + self.getCompanyLocation( companyRecord )
        print ""

    def getCompanyRecord( self ) :     
        try : 
            queryentity = self.sage.queryentity( self.companyId, "company" )
        except Exception as e: 
            self.abortOnException( "Get Company Record failure.", e )
        try : return queryentity.records
        except : return None 

    def getCompanyLocation( self, companyRecord ) :     
        try : 
            return (companyRecord.address.records.city + ", " +
                    companyRecord.address.records.state)
        except : return ""

# Entry point        
if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```